# Possible to do math inside of a sum statement?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm by no means an expert in DB2 so apologies if this is a novice question.  I am looking for a specific requirement.  I am summing through a table based on a case statement but am wondering if we could subtract an amount if a field is present in the row.

```
SELECT CODE, 
SUM(CASE SUBSTR(DATE,4,2)
    WHEN '01' THEN AMT
    END) as JanuaryTotal
FROM Table1
```

I'm looking to see if we can simply, if another field is present, if we can instead of summing it, simply subtract it from the total that is currently in place.

```
SELECT CODE, 
SUM(CASE SUBSTR(DATE,4,2)
    WHEN '01' THEN CASE WHEN TYPE = 'X' 
    THEN - AMT // some possible way to do this?
    ELSE AMT
    END) as JanuaryTotal
FROM Table1
```

Again, apologies.  i know this code doesnt run but just giving a visual of something to see if it's possible to do.

Comment: Can you edit your question with some sample input data and sample output data?

Comment: Can you post the working code atleast

Comment: Hi, can you try removing space between - and AMT and putting another END after the END keyword?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CODE, SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(DATE,4,2) = '01' THEN AMT
    WHEN TYPE = 'X' THEN 0 - AMT
    ELSE AMT
  END
) as JanuaryTotal
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to indent.  Also, it is not quite clear what to do if the sub-string is not 01 -- I'm guessing you don't want to add anything.

```
SELECT CODE, 
SUM(CASE SUBSTR(DATE,4,2)
      WHEN '01' THEN 
        CASE 
          WHEN TYPE = 'X' THEN -1 * AMT
          ELSE AMT
        END
      ELSE 0 -- SUBSTR(DATE,4,2) is not '01'
    END) as JanuaryTotal
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest final query is to flatten out your conditions so they stand alone:

```
SELECT CODE, SUM(CASE
  WHEN SUBSTR(DATE,4,2) AND TYPE = 'X' THEN 0-AMT
  WHEN SUBSTR(DATE,4,2) AND THEN AMT END) as JanuaryTotal
FROM Table1
```

Note that there are two forms of `CASE`:

```
CASE <expression>
    WHEN <value> THEN ...
    WHEN <value> THEN ...
```

and

```
CASE
    WHEN <condition> THEN ...
    WHEN <condition> THEN ...
```

I switched your query from using the first form to the second form.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CODE, SUM(
CASE
WHEN SUBSTR(DATE,4,2) = '01' and TYPE = 'X'  THEN -AMT
else AMT
END
) as JanuaryTotal
FROM Table1
group by CODE
```